# How to ensure that props passed through the Functional Components are always updated, and not writing a useEfflect for props at each level?

Tags: reactjs

How to ensure that props passed through the Functional Components are always updated, and not writing a useEfflect for props at each level?

I have a chain of 5 functional classes and when I pass props, and then update them from top to bottom, I need to add an effect and state at each level. This does not make my life easy. It's a lot of code that should be automatically generated.

What solutions do you use for this?

Comment: Can you post some code examples? My first thought is unless if you need to manipulate the data in some way, you don't need to assign the new props to state and implement the `useEffect` hook to handle when these values change.

Comment: you are right. the problem was in a Select control that did not have the key being set and it did not change with the props:    <Select
                key={`${props.column.columnId}`}
                defaultValue={defValue}